# Exploding multipart polygons within shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I've got a shapefile with polygons, some of which are multipart polygons.  I need to create individual polygons out of the multipart polygons.

Is there a tool or plugin that can do this in QGIS 1.8?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In QGIS 1.8 (Lisboa)

(No plugins required as it is standard)

**Vector>Geometry Tools> Multipart to singleparts**

This will create individual polygons from multipart polygons.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfect!

Comment: There also is a [Multipart Split](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174429/converting-selected-multipart-features-to-single-parts-in-qgis) plugin, described in another post. It allows you to convert "multipart to singlepart" within edit mode.