# Converting selected multipart features to single parts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, multipart, singlepart

I'm looking for a way to convert one or many selected multipart feature to different single part features without recreating another layer, the way Arcgis allow a user to select a multipart feature and convert it to single parts while editing.

Please note I'm not looking for the existing processing QGIS tool doing this for the whole layer, but a tool who could do it on choosen entities while I'm editing the layer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The **Multipart Split** plugin can do this during the *Edit* session and saves the results in the current layer instead of creating a new one. You can download this from the toolbar:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*

When enabled, it will appear in the *Edit* menu and should also appear as an icon in the toolbar:

[image: Multipart Split icon]

Comment: That was quickly answered ! And exactly what I was needing :) Thanks.

Comment: @RobinP - Most welcome buddy :)

Comment: @wiltomap Done ! Sorry, I don't ask questions often

Comment: @RobinP - No need to apologise buddy, glad your problem is solved :)

Comment: @wiltomap - Thank you mate but you really didn't have to do this ;)