# Vertex editor dialog

Tags: qgis, vertices

I have a little lack, because when my colleagues use QGIS, sometimes they make a mistake with merge function, but singlepart/multipart isn't solution.

A simple example:
Somebody accidentally merged two polygons
[image]

The split tool cannot be use in this situation, because these polygons not neighbouring. I see all vertices in vertex editor dialog, but dont separate polygons.

[image]

Opposite if I use ArcGIS sketch properties, which shows separate the polygons.

[image]

ArcGIS use part(x) separate lines, which help to the identification of the polygons, hereby separates objects.

I want to similar solution in QGIS, that capable this task but didn't find suitable tool/plugin

Comment: In ArcGIS it is called Explode. Seems possible in QGIS using a plugin: [Converting selected multipart features to single parts in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174429/converting-selected-multipart-features-to-single-parts-in-qgis)

Comment: i am looking for the solution a better vertex editor, but this tool is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I am going to take a guess that what you want is the `Digitizing Tools` plugin.  This is different to the standard `Digitizing Toolbar` (note the very similar names!).  In the `Digitizing tools` plugin you have access to tools to split multipart features, divide polygons etc. during an edit session (ie on a per feature basis rather than all features as per the Multipart to Singleparts tool in the Vector->Geometry tools - which you said you don't want).  You can also find a tool to split features in the `Advanced Digitizing tools` - which may be another option.