# Splitting feature into individual features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, features, splitting

In QGIS I have a layer that is made up of a large number of polygons that are merged together to form one feature. Is it possible to split this feature into the individual polygons that make it up so I can preform analysis on the different polygons.

The screenshot below shows the layer and the associated attribute table I want to split.

[image]

Comment: Look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/174430/123828

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Multipart to Singlepart](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)

> Splits multipart features in the input layer into singlepart features.

From one multipolygon to 2786 single part polygons:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer worked perfect.

Comment: Sweden is the second with the number of islands 