# Delete more than one polygon at a time with Delete Part tool

Tags: qgis, polygon, delete

I'm using QGIS 3.22. When using the **Delete Part** tool it can be pretty tedious when you have a lot of unwanted polygons to delete. As it stands, I only know how to delete one poly at a time. Is there possibly a way to select multiple at once?

I've tried clicking and dragging, but that does nothing.

For example, I have a countries.geojson I'm working with. With the United States poly selected it includes tons of tiny islands everywhere. I'm currently deleting them one by one so the map centers more directly on the US mainland (I've already deleted Alaska). It would be nice to grab huge areas at once.
[image]

Comment: Is your US polygon one Multipart polygon ? (Only one entry in the attribute table / all polygons.arr always selected together). If so you need to convert it with the Multipart to singlepart tool. Then you'll be able to drag & select the subsets you need. Alternatively, you can use the 'select  by expression' tool to e.g select those with small areas/length

Comment: Yes, it's one multi-part polygon. I was looking for something like an "explode" tool. I installed the Multipart Split plugin. That's exactly what I was looking for! If you want to put that into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Now that I know the name of the plugin I also found an answer that suits my needs, however I came at it from a slightly different angle. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174429/converting-selected-multipart-features-to-single-parts-in-qgis

Comment: You should not need a plugin. In the Processing Toolbox, there is a native Milripart to Singlepart tool